# Loop asynchronosly through array

Tags: javascript, loops, asynchronous, reduce

I have following code:

```
var obj = {
   "slot1": ["1", "2"],
   "slot2": ["7", "5"],
   "slot3": ["12", "213"],
};

for (var key of Object.keys(obj )) {
   obj[key].reduce((chain, user_id) => {
    return chain
    .then(() => async_things_happen)
    .then(result => {
        other_things_happen
    });
  }, Promise.resolve()).then(() => {

  });
}
```

As you can see this does not work. So the content of the for loop works pretty well. It goes through the array and works well, but the for loop itself is the problem. How can I get the for loop wait for the inner content to finish before going to the next key?
The timeline should be as followed: `key(slot1) --> .reduce stuff --> key(slot2) --> .reduce stuff --> key(slot3) --> .reduce stuff --> fire finish`
I experimented with many different structures and can't find a solution.

**ADDITION**

```
async function test(obj) {
  return dosomething.then(()=> {
    return Object.keys(obj).reduce((chain, key) => {
      return chain.then(() => {
        return obj[key].reduce((chain, user_id) => {
            return chain.then(() => {dosomething})
        }, Promise.resolve());
      }, Promise.resolve());
    }).then(() => {
      console.log("LOOPED TROUGH ALL KEYS AND ARRAYS");
    });
  });
}
```

Thanks in advance,
filip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `.reduce` strategy for the inner loop is good but the outer loop is still synchronous, and starts a promise chain for each key all at the same time. Apply the same thing to the outer loop:

```
Object.keys(obj).reduce((chain, key) => {
    return chain.then(() => {
        return obj[key].reduce((chain, user_id) => {
            return chain.then(() => asyncStuff())
        }, Promise.resolve())
}, Promise.resolve())
```

Or with `async/await` it becomes a friendlier loop:

```
for (var key in obj) {
    for (var user_id of obj[key]){
        await asyncStuff()
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. So I played around a little bit and the solution with async and await I like best, but unfortunately, I can not use await in my special case, so I have to understand your first code snippet completely. I added a code example to my post. Can you please have a look at it? I always get the error: `TypeError: chain.then is not a function`